# WPF - Moving a Canvas

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have trouble with moving a canvas in a Window.

```
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Height="200" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,15,92,54" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFECECEC" Grid.RowSpan="2" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" >
        <TextBox Height="100" Width="100" Margin="50,50,327,65" Background="Red"/>
        <TextBox Height="100" Width="100" Margin="10,15,327,65" Background="Blue" />
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
```

This is code behind:

```
    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas1.CaptureMouse();
        point = Mouse.GetPosition(Grid1);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Canvas1.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            translate.X = e.GetPosition(Grid1).X - point.X;
            translate.Y = e.GetPosition(Grid1).Y - point.Y;
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas1.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

First time, it seem woork fine.
But second time i try to click on my canvas, this move but from initial position.
How can i fix it?

Comment: What is `Grid1`?

Comment: Grid1 is the first mainGrid of the Window.   <window><grid><canvas>

Comment: Anyway, on mouse down you initialize `point = Mouse.GetPosition(Grid1);` and subsequently move by the difference vector from that point. Obviously you start with a difference of `(0,0)` again. Probably add `translate.X` and `translate.Y` to `point` on initialization.

Comment: @Clemens Still doesn't work.  I also tried with this line in Canvas_MouseDown event: `point = new Point(translate.X, translate.Y);`  Thanks for helping me, i'm new in C# and Wpf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing `point` on mouse down, subtract the current translation:

```
private void Canvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas1.CaptureMouse();
    point = Mouse.GetPosition(Grid1);
    point.X -= translate.X;
    point.Y -= translate.Y;
}
```

Alternatively, always only add the difference vector:

```
private void Canvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas1.CaptureMouse();
    point = Mouse.GetPosition(Grid1);
}

private void Canvas1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Canvas1.IsMouseCaptured)
    {
        var p = e.GetPosition(Grid1);
        var diff = p - point;
        point = p;

        translate.X += diff.X;
        translate.Y += diff.Y;
    }
}
```

---

Also make sure the Grid doesn't position the Canvas, by setting the Canvas alignment to Top/Left:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ...>
```

And probably don't set a Margin, but instead initialize the TranslateTransform appropriately.